# Date Conversion YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD in Data weave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

In an API QueryParameter, I am using the Date as "yyyyMMdd" format. Can anyone help me to convert this to a Date format("yyyy-Mm-dd") in Data weave 2.0

Eg(https://localhost:9103/api/Endpoint?FromDate=20190930)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer assumes that you know how to procure the value from a query param. As well I think you meant to format it into "yyyy-MM-dd" format instead of "yyyy-Mm-dd" ?

if so , the following should help

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"20190930"  as Date {"format": "yyyyMMdd"} as String {"format": "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

**Output**

```
"2019-09-30"
```